# Is there a way to combine these two regex?

Tags: c++, regex

Right now I'm processing the following two regex replacements and I'm combining the substitution like this. Is there a way to process the replacement calling `regex_replace` one time only?

```
  std::string test_string = "whatever";
  std::regex reg_num("\\\"([0-9]+\\.{0,1}[0-9]*)\\\"");
  std::regex reg_newline("\n+");
  return std::regex_replace(std::regex_replace(test_string, reg_num, "$1"), reg_newline, "");
```

Comment: on a side note, I would prefer https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions over regex header

Comment: i don't do a heavy use of regexprs in this project. Actually, I think I'll use it 2/3 time only. But I'll check that lib out for the future so thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```cpp
std::string test_string = "\"1\" \"1.50\"\nNew line";
std::regex reg_combined("\"([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\"|\n");
std::cout << std::regex_replace(test_string, reg_combined, "$1");
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/7jSRh9).

The `$1` backreference is initialized with an empty string if Group 1 did not participate in the match, so it is safe to remove line feeds like this.

*Pattern details*:

- `"` - a `"` char (note you do not need to escape it)
- `([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)` - Group 1: one or more digits, an optional `.` and then zero or more digits (are you sure you do not need `[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`?)
- `"` - a `"` char
- `|` - or
- `\n` - a line feed char.

Comment: I didn't know that `$1` initialization property. Thanks!

Comment: I would use raw string literal for that: `R"re("([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)"|)re" "\n"` since it is easier to maintain it https://ideone.com/GZYZ1N

Comment: @MarekR Yes, `reg_combined(R"r("(\d+\.?\d*)"|\n)r")` [should work](https://ideone.com/6jdEJa), too.